# read statement help in bash to validate any key pressed

Tags: bash

when I use read statement in shell

```
read -n 1 -s -t 5 -p "Starting the script in 5 seconds. Press any key to stop!" yn
```

How to check if any key is pressed or not , if a key is pressed then the script must exit otherwise , the script must continue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop and limit `read`'s time by one second:

```
#!/bin/bash
shouldStop=0
for (( i=5; i>0; i--)); do
    printf "\rStarting script in $i seconds. Press any key to stop!"
    read -s -n 1 -t 1 key
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        shouldStop=1
    fi
done

if [ $shouldStop==1 ]
then
    printf "do not run script"
else
    printf "run script"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
read -n 1 -s -t 5 -p "Starting the script in 5 seconds. Press any key to stop!" && \
    exit 1
```

When a key is read, `read` returns `0` which would allow `&&` to process the next statement `exit 1`. This would end your script.

You don't have to specify a variable as well so you wouldn't need it. `read` uses default variable `$REPLY`.